# Could somebody tell me why i am getting an unexpected indent error?

Tags: python, indentation

I am trying to use this code:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

but I am getting an unexpected indent error at the 'def **unicode**' line, however to me this looks correct. Does anybody know why?

Comment: With which editor do you create the file? Try to open it in vim or emacs, you might note the difference

Comment: Currently using notepad++ because I got annoyed with eclipse pydev taking too long to load. I'll give emacs a shout, see what its like

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing tabs and spaces on different lines, which is causing this problem. Use spaces only (and turn off tabs in your editor).

Specifically, it appears that your `pub_date` line is indented with 4 spaces, but the `def __unicode__` line is indented with a tab. Python does not know what your tab value is set to in your editor, so it makes the assumption that a tab means an 8 space indent. The easiest (and recommended) way to avoid this is to only use spaces.

From [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces):

> ### Tabs or Spaces?
>
> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.
>
> Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs.
>
> Python 3 disallows mixing the use of tabs and spaces for indentation.
>
> Python 2 code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively.
>
> When invoking the Python 2 command line interpreter with the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are highly recommended!